# File upload is not workign in Asp.net .HasFile always false

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am working in monoX CMS and trying to upload file.But file-upload's hasFile is always false.I am using server script in .aspx page.Below is my code.

```
     <script runat="server">
     protected void btn_click_me(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        dbOperations dbObj = new dbOperations();
        if (selected_file.HasFile)
        {
            string title = txt_file_title.Value.ToString();
            int f_type = Convert.ToInt32(dd_file_type.Value);

            dbObj.CreateSubmission(title, f_type, selected_file.PostedFile);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

My Html code is:

```
  <MonoX:StyledButton ID="btnSubmit" CommandName="submit" OnClick="btn_click_me" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="validate_submission" Text='Submit'>
  </MonoX:StyledButton>
```

Form tag seen in firebug is:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: 100%" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="/MyFolder/Submissions.aspx" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
```

Rendered File tag is:

```
<input type="file" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_cp_cp_cp_cp_selected_file" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00$cp$cp$cp$cp$selected_file">
```

Comment: Please post your rendered `<form>` element.

Comment: I Have added rendered form.

Comment: I also need you to post the rendered HTML file element too.

Comment: I also added rendered file element.